# Porting PyMC2 code to PyMC3 - hierarchical model for sports analytics

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

I tried the following code, but I ran into problems. 
I think .values is the problem but how do I encode this as a Theano object?

The following is my data source

```
home_team,away_team,home_score,away_score
Wales,Italy,23,15
France,England,26,24
Ireland,Scotland,28,6
Ireland,Wales,26,3
Scotland,England,0,20
France,Italy,30,10
Wales,France,27,6
Italy,Scotland,20,21
England,Ireland,13,10
Ireland,Italy,46,7
Scotland,France,17,19
England,Wales,29,18
Italy,England,11,52
Wales,Scotland,51,3
France,Ireland,20,22
```

Here is the PyMC2 Code which works:
    data_file = DATA_DIR + 'results_2014.csv'

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep=',')
# Or whatever it takes to get this into a data frame.
teams = df.home_team.unique()
teams = pd.DataFrame(teams, columns=['team'])
teams['i'] = teams.index
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='home_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_home'}).drop('team', 1)
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='away_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_away'}).drop('team', 1)
observed_home_goals = df.home_score.values
observed_away_goals = df.away_score.values
home_team = df.i_home.values
away_team = df.i_away.values
num_teams = len(df.i_home.drop_duplicates())
num_games = len(home_team)
g = df.groupby('i_away')
att_starting_points = np.log(g.away_score.mean())
g = df.groupby('i_home')
def_starting_points = -np.log(g.away_score.mean())

#hyperpriors
home = pymc.Normal('home', 0, .0001, value=0)
tau_att = pymc.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1, value=10)
tau_def = pymc.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1, value=10)
intercept = pymc.Normal('intercept', 0, .0001, value=0)
#team-specific parameters
atts_star = pymc.Normal("atts_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_att, 
                        size=num_teams, 
                        value=att_starting_points.values)
defs_star = pymc.Normal("defs_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_def, 
                        size=num_teams, 
                        value=def_starting_points.values) 

# trick to code the sum to zero constraint
@pymc.deterministic
def atts(atts_star=atts_star):
    atts = atts_star.copy()
    atts = atts - np.mean(atts_star)
    return atts

@pymc.deterministic
def defs(defs_star=defs_star):
    defs = defs_star.copy()
    defs = defs - np.mean(defs_star)
    return defs

@pymc.deterministic
def home_theta(home_team=home_team, 
               away_team=away_team, 
               home=home, 
               atts=atts, 
               defs=defs, 
               intercept=intercept): 
    return np.exp(intercept + 
                  home + 
                  atts[home_team] + 
                  defs[away_team])

@pymc.deterministic
def away_theta(home_team=home_team, 
               away_team=away_team, 
               home=home, 
               atts=atts, 
               defs=defs, 
               intercept=intercept): 
    return np.exp(intercept + 
                  atts[away_team] + 
                  defs[home_team])   

home_points = pymc.Poisson('home_points', 
                          mu=home_theta, 
                          value=observed_home_goals, 
                          observed=True)
away_points = pymc.Poisson('away_points', 
                          mu=away_theta, 
                          value=observed_away_goals, 
                          observed=True)

mcmc = pymc.MCMC([home, intercept, tau_att, tau_def, 
                  home_theta, away_theta, 
                  atts_star, defs_star, atts, defs, 
                  home_points, away_points])
map_ = pymc.MAP( mcmc )
map_.fit()

mcmc.sample(200000, 40000, 20)
```

My attempt at porting to PyMC3 :) 
And I include the wrangling code.
I defined my own data directory etc.

```
data_file = DATA_DIR + 'results_2014.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep=',')
# Or whatever it takes to get this into a data frame.
teams = df.home_team.unique()
teams = pd.DataFrame(teams, columns=['team'])
teams['i'] = teams.index
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='home_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_home'}).drop('team', 1)
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='away_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_away'}).drop('team', 1)
observed_home_goals = df.home_score.values
observed_away_goals = df.away_score.values
home_team = df.i_home.values
away_team = df.i_away.values
num_teams = len(df.i_home.drop_duplicates())
num_games = len(home_team)
g = df.groupby('i_away')
att_starting_points = np.log(g.away_score.mean())
g = df.groupby('i_home')
def_starting_points = -np.log(g.away_score.mean())

import theano.tensor as T
import pymc3 as pm3
#hyperpriors


x = att_starting_points.values
y = def_starting_points.values
model = pm.Model()
with pm3.Model() as model:
    home3 = pm3.Normal('home', 0, .0001)
    tau_att3 = pm3.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1)
    tau_def3 = pm3.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1)
    intercept3 = pm3.Normal('intercept', 0, .0001)
    #team-specific parameters
    atts_star3 = pm3.Normal("atts_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_att3, 
                        observed=x)
    defs_star3 = pm3.Normal("defs_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_def3,  
                        observed=y) 
    #Seems to be the error here. 
    atts = pm3.Deterministic('regression', 
    atts_star3 - np.mean(atts_star3))
    home_theta3 = pm3.Deterministic('regression', 
    T.exp(intercept3 + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team]))
atts = pm3.Deterministic('regression', atts_star3 - np.mean(atts_star3))
    home_theta3 = pm3.Deterministic('regression', T.exp(intercept3 +     atts[away_team] + defs[home_team]))
    # Unknown model parameters
    home_points3 = pm3.Poisson('home_points', mu=home_theta3, observed=observed_home_goals)
    away_points3 = pm3.Poisson('away_points', mu=home_theta3, observed=observed_away_goals)
    start = pm3.find_MAP()
    step = pm3.NUTS(state=start)
    trace = pm3.sample(2000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)

    pm3.traceplot(trace)
```

And I get an error like values isn't a Theano object. 
I think this is the .values part above. But i'm confused about how to convert this into a Theano tensor. The tensors are confusing me :)

And the error for clarity, because I've misunderstood something in PyMC3 syntax.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-ce51c1a64412> in <module>()
     23 
     24     #Seems to be the error here.
---> 25     atts = pm3.Deterministic('regression', atts_star3 - np.mean(atts_star3))
     26     home_theta3 = pm3.Deterministic('regression', T.exp(intercept3 + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team]))
     27 

/Users/peadarcoyle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   2733 
   2734     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 2735                             out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
   2736 
   2737 def std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False):

/Users/peadarcoyle/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     71         ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
     72     else:
---> 73         ret = ret / rcount
     74 
     75     return ret

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'ObservedRV' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you add data so that I can reproduce your error?  A small simulated example will be fine, as long as it raises the same error you find with your real data. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Abraham I fixed this and added this.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary to convert arrays to tensors. I still don't see the error you're actually getting. Are you running the latest PyMC3? I only get "NameError: name 'defs' is not defined", which makes sense because its not defined.

Comment: Also, unless you have missing values or you really care about "tau_att3" or "tau_def3" (but you don't use them), I don't think its necessary to model "atts_star" and "defs_star" with Normal distribution, you can just use the data directly.

Comment: Do you have a PyMC2 version that works?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamDFlaxman I added the PyMC2 code thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my translation of your PyMC2 model:

```
model = pm.Model()
with pm.Model() as model:
    # global model parameters
    home        = pm.Normal('home',      0, .0001)
    tau_att     = pm.Gamma('tau_att',   .1, .1)
    tau_def     = pm.Gamma('tau_def',   .1, .1)
    intercept   = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, .0001)

    # team-specific model parameters
    atts_star   = pm.Normal("atts_star", 
                           mu   =0,
                           tau  =tau_att, 
                           shape=num_teams)
    defs_star   = pm.Normal("defs_star", 
                           mu   =0,
                           tau  =tau_def,  
                           shape=num_teams)

    atts        = pm.Deterministic('atts', atts_star - tt.mean(atts_star))
    defs        = pm.Deterministic('defs', defs_star - tt.mean(defs_star))
    home_theta  = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[home_team] + defs[away_team]
    away_theta  = tt.exp(intercept + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team])

    # likelihood of observed data
    home_points = pm.Poisson('home_points', mu=home_theta, observed=observed_home_goals)
    away_points = pm.Poisson('away_points', mu=away_theta, observed=observed_away_goals)
```

The big difference, as I see it, between PyMC2 and 3 model building is that the whole business of initial values in PyMC2 is not included in model building in PyMC3.  It is pushed off into the model fitting portion of the code.

Here is a notebook that puts this model in context with your data and some fitting code: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/55e23195fe0a0b089103

Comment: Thanks Abraham. I'll add this to my PyData talk in London - but I'll be sure to reference you :).

Comment: Cool, and can you send the slides or a recording of talk?  Sounds interesting.

Comment: Know this is pretty old, but I tried to replicate the results, and Pymc3 ends up with very different posteriors (e.g., home coefficient being around 0.0).

Comment: Caution, there is an error in this code. The line for home_theta must read home_theta  = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[home_team] + defs[away_team]       Without the fix, you get different results than in pymc2. Took me a while to find this! This likely also explains fsociety's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is failing because you can't use NumPy functions on theano tensors. Thus

```
np.mean(atts_star3)
```

Will give you an error. You can remove `atts_star3  = pm3.Normal("atts_star",...)` and just use the NumPy array directly `atts_star3 = x`.

I don't think you need to explicitly model `tau_att3`, `tau_def3`  or `defs_star` either.

Alternatively, if you want to keep those variables you can replace `np.mean` with `theano.tensor.mean`, which should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I tried that and I got Observed RV can't work with int. I think this model uses the normal distribution of the atts_star3 etc - since it is in the paper I based the code on.  I think I'll need to do some refactoring of the code and I'll see what happens next.

Comment: So after followed your advice. But now I get this error. 
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-07dd9000673b> in <module>()
     67 
     68 
---> 69     home_theta3 = pm3.Deterministic('regression', T.exp(intercept3 + atts3[away_team] + defs3[home_team]))
     70     away_theta3 = pm3.Deterministic('regression', T.exp(intercept3 +     atts3[away_team] + defs3[home_team]))
     71     # Unknown model parameters

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: looks like atts3 or defs2 is actually a function somehow. Maybe you ran the commented out code above?

Comment: Yeah when I commented out that code and just added a mu myself and it ran for me. I'll investigate it a bit more later on today. But I think it works as a 'hacky' example of the power of PyMC3. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

So I did this. It isn't a direct port of my previous version but it gives me an answer. Does anyone have any feedback?

```
import os
import math
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm3# I know folks are switching to "as pm" but I'm just not there yet
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import seaborn as sns
import theano.tensor as T
figsize(12, 12)
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data/')
data_file = DATA_DIR + 'results_2014.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep=',')
# Or whatever it takes to get this into a data frame.
teams = df.home_team.unique()
teams = pd.DataFrame(teams, columns=['team'])
teams['i'] = teams.index
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='home_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_home'}).drop('team', 1)
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='away_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_away'}).drop('team', 1)
observed_home_goals = df.home_score.values
observed_away_goals = df.away_score.values
home_team = df.i_home.values
away_team = df.i_away.values
num_teams = len(df.i_home.drop_duplicates())
num_games = len(home_team)
g = df.groupby('i_away')
att_starting_points = np.log(g.away_score.mean())
g = df.groupby('i_home')
def_starting_points = -np.log(g.away_score.mean())

import theano.tensor as T
import pymc3 as pm3
#hyperpriors

'''
def atts3(atts_star3=atts_star3):
    atts3 = atts_star.copy()
    atts3 = atts3 - np.mean(atts_star)
    return atts3
def defs3(defs_star3=defs_star3):
    defs3 = defs_star3.copy()
    defs3 = defs3 - np.mean(defs_star3)
    return defs
    '''
model = pm3.Model()
with pm3.Model() as model:
    home3 = pm3.Normal('home', 0, .0001)
    tau_att3 = pm3.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1)
    tau_def3 = pm3.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1)
    intercept3 = pm3.Normal('intercept', 0, .0001)
    #team-specific parameters
    atts_star3 = pm3.Normal("atts_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_att3, 
                        shape=num_teams, 
                        observed=att_starting_points.values)
    defs_star3 = pm3.Normal("defs_star", 
                        mu=0, 
                        tau=tau_def3, 
                        shape=num_teams, 
                        observed=def_starting_points.values) 


    #home_theta3 = atts3 + defs3
    #away_theta3 = atts3 + defs3
    # Unknown model parameters
    home_points3 = pm3.Poisson('home_points', mu=1, observed=observed_home_goals)
    away_points3 = pm3.Poisson('away_points', mu=1, observed=observed_away_goals)
    start = pm3.find_MAP()
    step = pm3.NUTS(state=start)
    trace = pm3.sample(2000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)

    pm3.traceplot(trace)
```

Comment: I'll post my translation of your PyMC2 code, which is a little different.

Comment: Cool :) Would love to see it.

Comment: I accepted your version Abraham. Mine is not as well written :)